# error in in fedora using matlab while uses this command

Tags: linux, matlab, gcc

I try to run the following command in MATLAB

```
i=imread(cameraman.tif);
imshow(i)
```

And I get the following error in MATLAB

> Error using axes
>   While setting the 'Parent' property of 'Axes':
>   Can't load '/usr/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwosgserver.so':
>   /usr/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/../../sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by
>   /lib64/libGLU.so.1)

What is the issue and how can I solve this?

Comment: You mean `i=imread('cameraman.tif');` right?

Comment: yes ..... i  tray this but hear i miss single cotation  'cameraman.tif'